# Pair object to contain 3 values coming from JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I want to keep 3 values from the JSON Response( Name, Latitude and Longitude) and pass it to the maps activity for marking in the gmaps.
But, List Pair(String,String) can take only 2 string arguments. How, to have a list pair with 3 arguments.

///Edited Code after getting the first Answer

```
 InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
       Log.v("Tag","Success");
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
       String line;
       while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           result.append(line);
       }

if(result != null){
           List<Pair<String, String>> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
           try

           {
               JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
               for (int i=0; i<result.toString().length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject jobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   String name = jobj.getString("NAME");
                   String latitude = jobj.getString("LATITUDE");
                   String Longitude = jobj.getString("LONGITUDE");
                   allNames.add(Pair.create(name, latitude));
               }

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
           }
}
```

Here result.toString() contains my output. For example

```
[{"MANDT":"200","NAME":"SOU1","LATITUDE":"37.2968812","LONGITUDE":"-81.2344122","CHANGE_TIME":"163724","CHANGE_DATE":"20160826"},{"MANDT":"200","NAME":"ss1","LATITUDE":"29.233232","LONGITUDE":"-81.23","CHANGE_TIME":"174709","CHANGE_DATE":"20160828"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> filedList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
try {
    String status = jsonObject.getString("STATUS");
    filedList.add(new Pair<String, String>("STATUS", status));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After you update, I see your json data become a little complex, so the use of `JSONObject` become less suitable.

My suggestion is to use a json library for your purpose, `GSON` is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for giving the right direction. Now, i want 3 values as a pair and keep it as an array. Any ideas?